# Creating object from dict changing field type

Tags: python, dictionary, object

I'm creating an object from a dict:

```
d = {'key1': value,
     'key2': ...,   }
```

My object has attributes same as all the keys from the dict. The problem is that the values from the dict are all `string` type, and I want to keep some of them in the object as `float`.
How can I do that? There are a lot of attributes (they are the same for each object), and I wouldn't like to repeat the same code for each attribute.

Comment: This depends on which fields you want to convert to `float`, and which you want to keep strings. I would recommend that your `__init__` method expect individual arguments, and define a class method that accepts a `dict`, does the necessary unpacking and conversions to `float`, and passes the resulting values to the `__init__` method.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "a lot of attributes", consider whether the class is too big in the first place.

Comment: @chepner - thanks for the answer. The class creates an abstract object that will create a record in the db. Each attribute is one field in the record in the table. 
So, would you recommend to implement the this conversion method for each argument that requires `str->float` conversion?